# Clearing user avatars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I usually get a db dump of our production data to test and fix bugs.  Since we allow users to upload their own avatars, I get a lot of 404 when I try to load a page which uses the user's avatars.  This affects my testing time so I want to clear all of the user's avatars from the db. Is there an easy way to do this?  I'm using paperclip.

```
User.rb

has_attached_file :avatar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best addressed using a rake task.

create a file called `avatars.rake` inside `lib/tasks`

```
desc "Clear all avatars"
task clear_avatars: :environment do
  User.find_each do |user|
    user.avatar = nil 
    user.save(validate: false)
  end 
end
```

Then just call `rake clear_avatars` on your terminal

Answer (score 0):

As jvnill says, you should remove that data manually.
However, if you have a lot of users, looping through them all will take a lot of time.

```
task clear_avatars: :environment do
  User.update_all 'avatar = NULL'
end
```

You're executing only one SQL query and removing all the avatars.

Comment: This is probably right but if I have uploaded some avatars locally, I'd have to delete the uploaded files myself